# Questions around sympy.UndefFunction and MatMul/DotProduct

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following code including 4 questions/problems:

```py
from sympy import Function
from sympy import MatMul
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import MatrixSymbol
from sympy import DotProduct
from sympy import Add


def main():
    n = Symbol('n', integer=True, positiv=True)
    m = Symbol('m', integer=True, positiv=True)

    t = Symbol('t', real=True)
    x = MatrixSymbol('x', n, 1)
    y = MatrixSymbol('y', m, 1)
    eta = MatrixSymbol('eta', 1, m)
    K = Function('K')  # should be a function from R^n to R^m

    # want to build the expression
    #   t + <eta, K(x) + y>

    # Q1: Why is K not recognized as callable?
    # Is this a problem with sympy or pylint?

    # pylint: disable=not-callable

    # Q2: Why is it that Add(...).doit() works but ... + ... not
    works = Add(y, K(x)).doit()
    print(f"works: {works}")
    try:
        _ = y + K(x)
    except TypeError as e:
        print(f"Addition fails for MatrixSymbol {y} and AppliedUndef "
              f"{K(x)} due to: {e}")

    # Q3: This seems resonable from the expected meaning of the classes but
    # the documentation is unclear. Especially for DotProduct saying it is
    # similar except for possibly not requiring transposition.
    works = t + DotProduct(eta, y)
    print(f"works: {works}")
    try:
        _ = t + MatMul(eta, y)
    except TypeError as e:
        print(f"Addition fails for real Symbol {t} and MatMul {MatMul(eta, y)}"
              f" due to: {e}")

    # Q4: Lastly the main problem is of course that neigher MatMul(eta, K(x))
    # nor DotProduct(eta, K(x)) work.
    for prod in [MatMul, DotProduct]:
        try:
            prod(eta, K(x))
        except (TypeError, NotImplementedError) as e:
            print(f"Could not multiply MatrixSymbol {eta} with AppliedUndef "
                  f"{K(x)} with {prod.__name__} due to: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The main point related to Q4 is that I do not know how to specify the signature of an `UnknownFunction`.
I guess this is not possible at the moment?
Is there a workaround?
Would it make sense to include anything like this into sympy?

What about the other questions.
Can anyone explain?
Would you consider any of them worth raising an issue at Github?

Many thanks to anyone who can help here.
Franz

Comment: `MatMul(eta, y)` has a `.shape` (1,1).  `DotProduct` does not.  Compare the `type(...).__mro__`.  Both problem additions give  a `TypeError: Mix of Matrix and Scalar symbols`

Comment: `numpy` freely mixes scalars and arrays.  But it appears that the `sympy` `Matrix` expressions/variables do not readily mix with Scalars.  I haven't used it much, but clearly the `Matrix` category in `sympy` is not a comprehensive calculation tool.

Comment: At least Q2 is worth considering in a GitHub issue. I don't know what hpaulj means by a "comprehensive calculation tool" but certainly it isn't expected to be able to freely combine things like scalar+matrix in sympy (or in Mathematics more generally).

Comment: `Add(y, K(x))` forms an `Add` object, but doesn't pass the arguments through the same sort of checks that `y.__add__` or `MatAdd` do.  @OscarBenjamin

Comment: @hpaulj That is true but I also use the `.doit()` method of `Add` shouldn't that trigger the same "checks" as `__add__`? To state thinks differently one could say "Why are the checks necessary if I can get a result with `Add(...).doit()` anyway. Either the result is "worng" or the checks of `__add__` are to strickt.

Comment: As I said Q2 is worth opening an issue on GitHub for. They should both raise TypeError.

Comment: `Add` by default does `evaluate`.  `doit` is a method defined by a superclass, `AssocOp`, and doesn't promise to further test the arguments.  `MatAdd` is a subclass of `Add`.  Python classes don't normally change "themselves" into a subclass.  But I'm still learning what an object like `Add` actually does, including what it means to "evaluate" such an instance.

Comment: `y+eta` complains about alignment, but neither `Add` or `MatAdd` check this. But looking at the code I see that `MatAdd` has a `check` option.  `y.__add__` does `MatAdd(self, other, check=True).doit()`.  That's also obvious in the full traceback for `y+K(x)`